# Marionette's bindTo and Backbone's once

Tags: marionette

Is there a Marionette Eventbinder analog to Backbone.Events.once?  Something like, 'bindToOnce'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and there likely won't be. Marionette's EventBinder will be deprecated in favor of Backbone.Events at some point in the near future.

You can accomplish the same thing by doing this, though:

`foo.bindTo(bar, "baz", _.once(myFunction));`

Comment: bindTo was replaced with listenTo a few versions back. Backbone.Events also has it's own "once" method on it, now, as well.